# SSIS fails to access file with UNC path

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've deployed a SSIS package to SQL Server, which should read data from flat file, which is located here:

[image]

I can access path just fine from my local machine and I can run package from Visual Studio just fine too, however once I try to execute it on SQL Server, I get the following error:

[image]

Currently (just to debug) everyone has full access to this folder.

How do I fix it so my package works fine? (P.S. I don't have sysadmin rights, could it be the reason?)

I'm using Windows Authentication to login into SQL Server.

I execute my package from SSISDB. Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: restart sql-server as administrator and try to execute

Comment: @bmsqldev I don't have rights to do that.

Comment: Are you running via the [SQL Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx)?  If so whatever account that is logged on as will need permissions to read from the source folder.

Comment: @destination-data No, package is deployed in SSISDB and I just execute it from there. Adding a screenshot for a reference. And like I've said - everyone has now full access to that folder

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas don't even try to "restart sql server as administrator"  - it doesn't even make sense. A *service* should never have to run as an administrator and packages *don't* run as SQL Server's account anyway

Comment: Probably the package is run with a service account. Try adding a Proxy to SQL Agent using your own credentials. Check this out: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190698(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: When you execute a package directly, it runs with *your* credentials. Can you access the file using *exactly* this path? Have you tried debugging the package in SSIS using the same path ?

Comment: What happens when you login to the SSIS box and try to navigate to that UNC path from the SSIS server?

Comment: Could we move to chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108935/ssis-fails-to-access-file-with-unc-path-discussion

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.  Agree that running the SQL Server as admin is bad idea.  But I think packages executed from the MSDB SSIS package store are run on the service account by default.  Like Steenbergh I would recommend trying a proxy.  OP - You can use profiler to check the account in play.

Comment: @destination-data no they don't use *SQL Server's* service account. They get executed by SQL Agent using its account or a proxy account. If executed from the menu, they impersonate the caller

Comment: Sorry @PanagiotisKanavos you are 100% correct.  Just read the docs :).  Probably should have done that first.

Comment: I can access path from my own machine (same WA credentials as logging to SQL Server instance)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I just noticed the error reads 'Cannot open file', not 'Cannot find file'. Can you open (and save) the file from Explorer? Isn't it locked or opened by another dev or anything? That's a common occurrence with SSIS and Excel files, don't know about TXT.

Comment: @steenbergh None of the applications have it open. Could it be permission issue (DBA from my team could execute package just fine, meanwhile I cannot).

Comment: I didn't ask whether you can access the path from your own machine.   The question is whether something on your network is blocking your SSIS machine from seeing the UNC path.  Although if the DBA can execute the package the same way you are attempting, then it is almost certainly permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on folder, properties--> In security tab, check whether your server account is added with full control permission. Lastly you can share the folder where file is placed with everyone, better to skip this sharing though if previous one works

Comment: Like I've said. Everyone has full access to this folder.